# iframe loads outside parent window

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, iframe

I am loading a content from another site in iframe window, but when I select any link it opens the parent site in the window. I need everything to be opened in the same iframe? How to fix that?

The code:

```
<div class="calculator" style="display: block;width: 900px; height: 440px; overflow: hidden; ">
<iframe src="http://www.avtosojuz.ua/technical_service/" align="middle" width="962" height="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="margin-top: -440px;
"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Wait...are you saying that if you click a link in the iframe, it loads that link in the parent window that holds the iframe in the DOM? [Because I can't replicate that](http://jsfiddle.net/a1f2k9kz/)

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked before: [How to open a iframe link within the same iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802765/how-to-open-a-iframe-link-within-the-same-iframe). It appears that it is not possible to control this when referencing an external website.